# How to keep track of columns that have been changed in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data, data-cleaning

I'm performing a lot of data cleaning and want to keep track of the rows that I have manipulated. Is there an elegant way to keep track of the changes I've made 
(ideally within a column of the dataframe)?

An example of my initial dataframe would be:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ind = pd.Index([pd.Timestamp('2019-03-17'), 
                pd.Timestamp('2019-03-18'), 
                pd.Timestamp('2019-03-20'),
                pd.Timestamp('2019-03-21'),
                pd.Timestamp('2019-03-22'),
                pd.Timestamp('2019-03-24')])

data = {'col':[25,25,24,3,25,24]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, ind)
```

```
            col
2019-03-17   25
2019-03-18   25
2019-03-20   24
2019-03-21    3
2019-03-22   25
2019-03-24   24
```

I'm performing several cleaning operations (which I'll call 'a' and 'b'), and I want to mark the rows that I have done these to in a new column.

```
# operation a: create full date range and forward fill the missing days

df = df.asfreq(freq='D', fill_value=np.nan)
df['col'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

# operation b: check for rate changes larger than a particular value and forward fill those rows

df.loc[df['col'].diff()<-3, 'col'] = np.nan
df['col'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

I'd like to add a column where I keep track of which rows I've performed these on, such that the output looks something like this:

```
             col changed
2019-03-17  25.0       0
2019-03-18  25.0       0
2019-03-19  25.0       a
2019-03-20  24.0       0
2019-03-21  24.0       b
2019-03-22  25.0       0
2019-03-23  25.0       a
2019-03-24  24.0       0
```

The best method I've thought of would be to create "shadow" dfs at each step, and compare the values before (the "shadow") and after (the new df), then modify the "changed" column if there are differences, but this feels very clunky. Is there a more concise way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the DataFrame contains a column named `changed` and filled with values other than `np.nan`, you can do the following:

```
# operation a
df = df.asfreq(freq='D', fill_value=np.nan)
df['col'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
df['changed'].fillna('a', inplace=True)

# operation b
df.loc[df['col'].diff()<-3, ['col', 'changed']] = [np.nan, 'b']
df['col'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! That is simple and makes sense.